# DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data()

Tags: stream-wrappers

`DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open` call failed in `file_unmanaged_save_data()`

I do not identify the problem. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by setting up temporary path i.e.

**Goto :**

> Home » Administration » Configuration » Media and fix temporary
>   directory.

or Goto to the path & add temp url :

```
config/media/file-system
```

[image]